# Redirect pattern file avoiding recursion loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, recursion

I have a downloadable file with the filename containing a version number, let's say download-3-0.dat, would be the current one.

I want to redirect external references to previous versions of the file to the current one so download-2-5.dat would redirect to download-3-0.dat

This seems a partial solution:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=CURRENT:3-0]

RewriteRule ^download(.*).dat$ http://site.com/download-%[ENV:CURRENT].dat [L, R=301]
```

But the problem is how do you add an exception to the current version so it does not enter a recursion loop (the last rewrite rule would redirect to itsef if the requested file is download-3-0.dat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace all of your code with this line:

```
RewriteRule ^download-(?!3-0\.dat$) /download-3-0.dat [L,R=301,NC]
```

**EDIT: Based on your comment below :-**

**Hmm this turned out to be way more tricky than I anticipated at start.**

Try this code:

```
# set your current version here
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^" CURRENT=3-0

RewriteCond %{ENV:CURRENT}:%{REQUEST_URI} !^([^:]+):/download-\1\.dat$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^download-[^.]+\.dat$ /download-%{ENV:CURRENT}.dat [L,R=301,NC]
```

**PS:** Since we cannot use `%` variables on RHS of `RewriteCond` as back-reference, I am using special regex back-reference variable `\1` in the `RewriteCond` here.

Comment: This one works indeed, thanks. As the real implementation involves more variations I was pretending to define the CURRENT variable once. With your method, at a change of version I'd have to modify it in several locations in the .htaccess file (possible mistype errors). I will wait some suggestion or some inspiration in this direction before using your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that las solution is perfect, thanks so much. (And I almost understand it!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a RewriteCond that confirms it isn't the current version:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=CURRENT:3-0]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^download-3-0.dat
RewriteRule ^download(.*).dat$ http://site.com/download-%{ENV:CURRENT}.dat [L, R=301]
```

You may have to tweak the pattern in the RewriteCond, but this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: The `CondPattern` part of [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) cannot contain environment variables, it must be a perl compatible regular expression, or a string. Also environment variables are accessed using curly braces.

Comment: Yes, as ndm says, the variable substitution is not done at in the CondPattern.